# Netsuite Sales orders suddenly have an additional step (complete) when done through CSV import

Tags: netsuite

I am updating my company's system so that it supports dropshipping items. Ever since I switched to this type of item it asks me to complete the order after I approved it. what is it that I am missing so that I can skip this step altogether, is it even possible to skip the step, or to complete multiple orders at the same time (like how you can approve multiple orders)?

It bears mentioning the Company operates in Mexico.

the steps I take are as follow:

1. I create and save a sales order, that is, I put in the client, the document and reference number, and the item, as well as a couple of custom fields
2. the next screen asks me to approve the order, I do it and it creates the matching purchase order
3. then instead of being able to invoice, I first have to "complete" which takes me to an order fulfillment form
4. I save that and the order can be invoiced.

Ideally, after approval, I would just be able to invoice

Comment: What are the manual steps you have to go through to complete the order?

Comment: @bknights So, after I create and save a sales order, that Is, I put in the client, the document and reference number, and the item, as well as a couple of custom fields, the next screen asks me to approve the order, I do it and it creates the matching purchase order, then instead of being able to invoice, I first have to "complete" which takes me to an order fulfillment form, I save that and the order can be invoiced. Ideally, after approval, I would just be able to invoice

Comment: You should add these steps to the question so the issue is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally a sales order is not invoicable until it's been fulfilled.
You can override that at a whole account level by going to

- Setup -> Accounting -> Accounting Preferences
- Order Management tab
- scroll to Invoicing
- check 'Invoice in Advance of Fulfillment'

Be aware this is a system level setting and if you used to be able to invoice before fulfillment someone else in your company may have unchecked this setting in the recent past.

Alternatively at the individual item level you can use the 'Can be fulfilled/received' checkbox to allow invoicing without fulfilling. Note that 'Can be fulfilled/received' may not be  changed after an item has been ordered.

Normally (US/Canada) an order should not be invoiced until it is shipped. Customer Deposits on Sales Orders are the preferred way to handle pre-payment for GAAP etc reasons.